# how to do login code in codeigniter...?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, authentication

I want to perform login code. I have one login form with two field named as Username and Password and table name in database is tbllogin which having login_name and password fields.
When I am executing it. I am getting the following error.

Message: Use of undefined constant error - assumed 'error'.
Filename: controllers/login.php

code:

```
public function processlogin()
{
    // $this->load->model('login_model');
    // $show =true;
    // $user = $this->login_model->showUser($show);
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('pass');

    $this->load->database();
    $query = $this->db->get_where('tbllogin', array('login_name' => $username));

    //$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM tbllogin');
    $this->load->library('encrypt');
    $key = '12345';

    $match = false;   
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $encrypted_password = $this->encrypt->decode($row->password,$key);
        if($password === $encrypted_password)
        {
            echo $row->login_name;
            echo $encrypted_password;
            $match = true;
        }
    }

    //echo 'Total Results: ' . $query->num_rows(); 
    if($match)
    {
        echo "success";
        $this->load->helper('url');
        redirect('/index.php/home');
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'error';
    }
}
```

Comment: This line is your problem `echo error;` try sth like `echo 'error';`

Comment: Thanks , I have tried it..but now it doesnt displaying any error message instead it just displaying as 'Error'.

Comment: What sort of error do you expect to see? DB, Input Validation, Exception ? The code above will check `if` there is a `password match` ,`else` it will print "Error" (e.g. Password doesn't match) as stated.

Comment: Can you please suggest me where the actul problem is there in code?

Comment: I want correct output. I am new to codeigniter. I dont understand exactly where error occurs in this code. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo error;
```

This statement is completely wrong. PHP thinks *error* is a constant. The solution for this is [Error Handling](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html).

Otherwise, use CI's form validation system and simply:

```
echo validation_errors();
```